# C# - When method arguments fail validation, should I kick back an exception?

Tags: c#, validation, exception, methods

I am putting together a technical analysis library that I hope others may use eventually, so I want to make sure I validate data going into my methods and return something appropriate. Right now, if the validation fails I have it returning a blank value. Would it be more appropriate to throw an exception? What is the better practice if other developers may use this library? Here is how I am validating currently:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the MACD (Moving Average Convergence Divergence) over n periods, where n is the number of elements in the input prices.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="InputValues">The numbers used for the MACD calculation. Index 0 must be the oldest, with each index afterwards one unit of time forward. There must more values present than what the SlowEMA calls for.</param>
    /// <param name="FastEMA">Optional: The smaller (faster) EMA line used in MACD. Default value is 12. Must be less than the SlowEMA.</param>
    /// <param name="SlowEMA">Optional: The larger (slower) EMA line used in MACD. Default value is 26. Must be less than the number of elements in InputValues.</param>
    /// <param name="SignalEMA">Optional: The EMA of the MACD line. Must be less than the FastEMA.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the components of a MACD, which are the MACD line itself, the signal line, and a histogram number.</returns>
    public MACD CalculateMACD(decimal[] InputValues, decimal FastEMA = 12M, decimal SlowEMA = 26M, decimal SignalEMA = 9M)
    {
        MACD result;

        // validate that we have enough data to work with
        if (FastEMA >= SlowEMA) { return result; }
        if (SlowEMA >= InputValues.Count()) { return result; }
        if (SignalEMA >= FastEMA) { return result; }

        // Do MACD calculation here


        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three standard Argument Exceptions in .Net:

- ArgumentException
- ArgumentNullException
- ArgumentOutOfRangeException

They all have overloads on their constructors to allow you to state which argument was an issue, and a more verbose message when throwing them.

It would be normal practice to use these.

Edit:

Further to null (or empty or whatever) being acceptable, I would still tend to throw the exception, as you don't necessarily know what the user of your library will be ok with. If they don't mind nulls, they can always catch the exception and handle it as appropriate.

However if you don't throw an exception then you are limited in your ability to tell the consumer of your library what the problem was.

Comment: This is better than just returning null, as you can indicate to the caller exactly the problem was.

Comment: These are all really good points. Since obviously there is a problem because validation failed, I should let the developer know  that there is a problem instead of masking it in a null value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This code won't compile since you try to return an unassigned variable. Assuming you really use `MACD result = new MACD();`, the answer is: it depends. Can you do *anything at all* with an initialized object? Then yes, it's fine to return that.

If not, you can `return null` and check for that, or simply `throw` an `ArgumentException()`.

Comment: Ah, I left out an important bit. It's a struct so its defaulting to the zero value of all its properties. Or so my unit testing is indicating.

Comment: @BillSambrone then exceptions are definitely the way to go, otherwise the caller can't know that anything went wrong at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the fact that exception should be thrown if your application runs into any erroneous or incorrect state which would cause damage if continued unhandled or without extra attention.

If you have too less data to produce a meaningful analysis it's up to you to decide whether the resulting calculations are correct / incorrect / harmful / etc.

You also have to take in mind that throwing an exception means interrupting the normal path of execution of your program and enter an additional path (the exception handling path).

I would inform the user of that situation with some kind of message and let the program terminate or continue in an ordinary way rather that forcibly throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If the `CalculateMACD` is used in a wrong way because absurd parameters were passed, this can be considered as a programming error and an exception should be thrown. Don't worry about the consequences of throwing an exception in this case, since it should only be thrown when testing the application on the development environment.

However, if the problematic parameters could be passed in a productive environment, you should decide whether this is a normal condition. In this case consider returning an appropriate information in the return value (either a special property or by returning `null` for instance.

If it is an exceptional condition that should not occur, throwing an exception is probably the better way. In this case make sure that the application will still run smoothly afterwards or at least ends with an appropriate and understandable message.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common good practice to validate your arguments. There are libraries where common argument checks are done, so that you don't have to repeat those checks. Here is one called [Argument Validator](https://github.com/rezahok/ArgumentValidator) which I wrote and use for my projects.

Sample usage would look like this:

```
public void AddPerson(string personId, Person personData)
        {
            Throw.IfNullOrEmpty(personId, nameof(personId));
            Throw.IfNull(personData, nameof(personData));
```

..

```
public void Compute(int generation)
        {
            Throw.IfNot(() => generation > 100);
```

..

```
 public void Compute(int generation)
        {
            Throw.IfOutOfRange(generation, 1, 100, nameof(generation));
```